# jQuery mobile, image map area, href and back button missing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, dictionary, area

I am using phonegap and jquery mobile for an ios app.

I now run into aproblem using image maps and the back button.

My code looks like that:

```
<img id="lagewanderwege" src="images/Lichtenstein/um_Lichtenstein.gif"  alt="" title="Sehenswürdikeiten um Lichtenstein" onclick="toggleLageImage();" usemap="#LandkarteLichtenstein">
<map name="LandkarteLichtenstein">
    <area style="cursor: pointer" shape="rect" coords="186,97,203,128"  data-transition="slide" onClick="location='#div_Lichtenstein_1';" alt="Burgruine Lichtenstein" title="Burgruine Lichtenstein" />
</map>

<div id="div_Lichtenstein_1" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true"> 
    <div data-role="header">

..
</div>

<div id="div_Lichtenstein" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" onmouseover="pauseAudio();">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 id="div_Lichtenstein_header">Archäologisch-historische Rundreise um die Burgruine Lichtenstein</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="div_video_lichtenstein" data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#div_Lichtenstein_1" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/Lichtenstein/po_ruine_head.jpg" alt="Burgruine Lichtenstein" class="ui-li-icon" />&nbsp;1 - Burgruine Lichtenstein</a></li>

...
</div>
```

If I click on the ul list view a link the back button is shown for the div_Lichtenstein_1 page.

But If I click on the map area onclick it does not display the back button for the div_Lichtenstein_1 page. Same happens when I directly use href= instead of onclick.

I assume jquery mobile does something special with the first a href click. I can see this when I first click on the list view a href item - back button exists. If I I next click on the map area link (same reference) the back button exists.

If I do it in the reverse order - first map area click, then a href click the back button does not exist.

Any idea what's wrong or what I need to modify?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Instead of `onclick=location` use this little code `$('map_id').on('click', function () { $.mobile.changePage('#page_id'); });` JQM uses Ajax navigation to navigate between pages, once you you go to a page using Ajax, it will be registered in history and thus back button will be shown.

Comment: Thanks for this solution proposal. I got it working based on this tip. I changed the code as follows:    <area id="LandkarteLichtensteinArea1" style="cursor: pointer" shape="rect" coords="186,97,203,128"  data-transition="slide" onClick="$.mobile.changePage('#div_Lichtenstein_1');" alt="Burgruine Lichtenstein" title="Burgruine Lichtenstein" /> With this modification it works perfectly. Thanks again for the tip!